# How to remove brackets

Tags: regex

I have a RegEx to extract values in brackets [] from a string that actually is configured like this:

```
[^\[]*(\[.*?\])[^\[]*
$1;
```

The upper regex give me the following output which is mostly what I need:

```
[Value1];[Value2];[Value3];
```

Finally I would like to have the same values but without the brackets:

```
Value1;Value2;Value3;
```

Can someone give me the right trick to achieve this?
I guess it must be a little thing.

Comment: What is the tool(s) you're using? The task seems easy with standard Unix tools.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could define the group `(\[.*?\])` as `\[(.*)?\]`.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, it will match `Value1];[Value2];[Value3` or so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified what tool you are using,
I’m going to guess that it is something similar to `sed -E`
(or `sed -r`, in GNU-land). 
I guess you have input like

```
The;quick brown;[fox];[jumps];[over];the;lazy dog.
```

and you are doing something equivalent to

```
sed -E 's/[^\[]*(\[.*?\])[^\[]*/\1;/'
```

and getting the output

```
[fox];[jumps];[over];
```

— but you want

```
fox;jumps;over;
```

I believe that you cannot do that with a single regular expression;
i.e., a single substitute command. 
(I can’t be sure, since I don’t know what tool you are using.) 
But you can string multiple individual `sed` commands together
in a single *invocation* of `sed` —
so just add a second substitute command to remove the brackets:

```
sed -E -e 's/[^\[]*(\[.*?\])[^\[]*/\1;/' -e 's/[][]//g'
```

If the values can ***contain*** square brackets, this will remove them as well.

Note that, at least for `sed`,
you don’t need all the backslashes in the left side of the substitute:

```
sed -E -e 's/[^[]*(\[.*?])[^[]*/\1;/'    -e 's/[][]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This perl one-liner does the job:

```
cat file.txt 
val11;val12;[val13];val14;[val15];[val16]
val21;val22;[val23];val24;[val25];[val26]

perl -ape 's/\[(.*?)\]|[^\[\]\r\n]*/{$1?$1.";":""}/eg' file.txt 
val13;val15;val16;
val23;val25;val26;
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/                  # substitute
    \[                  # opening square bracket
      (.*?)             # group 1, 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \]                  # closing square bracket
  |                   # OR
    [^\[\]\r\n]*        # 0 or more any character that is NOT square brackets or linebreaks
/                   # With
    {                   # code
      $1?                 # if group 1 exists (i.e. thhere is something inside square brackets)
        $1.";"              # take it and add semicolon
      :                   # else
        ""                  # insert empty string
    }                   # end code
/eg                 # end substitute, eval code, global
```